# Angular not ordering data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

i've been trying to get angular js to order my data for me. But alas it is not working

Im retrieving data from firebase (https://boiling-inferno-4886.firebaseio.com/champion) and using node js to send it to a controller.

Controller Code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


// Pulls list of games
$scope.pullGame = function() {
  console.log("Here");
  $http.get('/getGameData').success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.championlist = response;
  });

};  
}]);
```

Then im displaying the information using ng-repeat

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<title>DevCha</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container"  ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<input class="form-control" ng-model="game.name">
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="pullGame()">Update</button>

<h1>DevCha</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead >
    <tr>
        <th>Champion Name</th>
        <th>Wins</th>
        <th>Losses</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="champion in championlist|orderBy: 'name'">
        <td>{{champion.name}}</td>
        <td>{{champion.wins}}</td>
        <td>{{champion.losses}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>


<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using firebase to sort the data but that isn't working either (which is bizarr). But im happy if either will sort for me (angular or firebase)

Node Js code that pushes the data to angular

```
app.get('/getGameData', function(req, res){

    var ref = new Firebase("https://boiling-inferno-4886.firebaseio.com/champion");

    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      // Success
      console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
      res.json(snapshot.val());

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      //callback("Failure", null);
    });

});
```

Sample_Data - 1: {name: 'Jim', Wins: 10, Losses: 5}, 2: {name: 'Fred', Win:8, Losses: 5}
(Actual data can be found at the firebase link)

tl:dr i need to order my data, i tried using firebase's inbuilt methods to sort it and angular's | orderBy but neither are working

Comment: What exactly isnt working? Are you getting an error? Also, I recommend trying to use a local copy of the data to see if your `orderBy` works.

Comment: Can you please paste the sample data ?

Comment: the data is located at the link on firebase. No there are no errors the data displays perfectly, but is not ordered by what i specified (name).

Answer (score 0):

We really need to look at that data , but as I had this problem before then here is my answer .

as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) , orderBy orders only arrays. The (key, value) syntax works on objects. Maybe transform your dictionary in an array will do the trick.

if not , you can write a filter to do that for you . look at this filter :

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function () {
  return function (items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if (reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

then you can use it like this :

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy:'position'">

</div>
```

by the way , you can change the order like this :

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy:'color':true">{{ item.color }</li>
</ul>
```

false is ascending and true is descending